# Subtracting single value across multiple data table rows with criteria

Tags: r, data.table

I have a set of nonnegative integer values on a data.table column and a single value (`n`) which I need to subtract.

If the value of `n` is for example 34, then the total number subtracted from all the values in the data.table column would need to be 34 (i.e. not 34 subtracted from each value).

There are however a couple of constraints. If a 0 value is present then this value must remain 0 and if any value is above 0 then it cannot finish being lower than 1. Finally, I would like the subtraction to be random so (if mathematically possible) I don't get the same result each time.

Here is some sample data:

```
library(data.table)
n = 34
dt1 <- data.table(SIZE = c(12,0,28,3,42,57))
```

These are two examples of outputs, based on the sample data, that would meet my criteria:

```
s1 <- data.table(SIZE = c(1,0,18,1,40,48))
s2 <- data.table(SIZE = c(2,0,24,3,42,37))
```

Comment: This is ill-defined. What if an entry is 0.5? That's above zero and less than one, so you're going to *raise* it? And what do you do if your criteria are infeasible? If all numbers are nonnegative integers, that makes it doable, but you'd want to specify that...

Comment: @Frank Sorry. The numbers in my scenario are all nonnegative integers. I have clarified the question in case anyone is looking for the solution to a similar problem in the future. Also, in my scenario if the operation is infeasible then it just gets skipped before it gets to stage where your solution is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [drawing from an urn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urn_problem) without replacement. The number of "balls" associated with each row is

```
dt1[, pmax(SIZE-1L, 0)]
# [1] 11  0 27  2 41 56
```

If there are fewer than `n` balls, your problem is infeasible. Otherwise, you can use `sample`:

```
set.seed(1)
dt1[, sample(rep(.I, pmax(SIZE-1L, 0)), n)]
# [1] 3 5 5 6 3 6 6 6 6 1 6 3 6 5 6 5 6 6 5 6 6 3 5 3 3 5 1 5 6 6 5 5 6 3
```

To apply this draw...

```
set.seed(1)
draw <- dt1[, .( r = sample(rep(.I, pmax(SIZE-1L, 0)), n))][, .N, by=r]
dt1[, NEW_SIZE := SIZE ][ draw$r, NEW_SIZE := SIZE - draw$N ]
#    SIZE NEW_SIZE
# 1:   12       10
# 2:    0        0
# 3:   28       21
# 4:    3        3
# 5:   42       32
# 6:   57       42

# verify 
dt1[, sum(SIZE  - NEW_SIZE)] == n
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I'm going ahead and assuming the OP is working with counts (nonnegative integers).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That does exactly what I am after. Also, your assumption was correct.